.NET 8: return the response 200 immediately for long running process
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API endpoint that will be called from a WPF client application. This endpoint needs to process a large amount of data sent from the WPF client. The client doesn't need to wait for the processing to complete; it only needs to know that the request reached the API successfully.
Given that we have about 2,000 users using the WPF application, my goal is to ensure that the API endpoint quickly returns a 200 OK response to the client while triggering a long-running task to process the data. This way, the client doesn't experience a delay while the server handles the background processing.
Here's what I've done so far:

I have implemented the endpoint in a Web API controller.
I have set up logging and exception handling for the long-running task.
I am considering using a HostedService for background processing.
However, I'm facing a challenge with HostedService. It only takes a CancellationToken as a parameter for the ExecuteAsync method, but I need to pass the data that the endpoint receives to the background service for processing.

Could you suggest the best way to implement this pattern?
Specifically: how can I create a background service that can receive data from the API endpoint?
What are the limitations of this approach, and are there better alternatives for this kind of requirement?
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitOrder([FromBody] List<Order> orders)
{
    await _transactionProcessor.CreateOrders(orders); // this is the long running task

    return Ok();
}

The processor
public class TransactionProcessor : ITractionProcessor
{
     public async Task<TransactionResponse> CreateOrders(List<Order> orders)
     {
         await Task.Delay(5000);
         // process orders that takes large amount of time.
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}


Have you seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio? There is a section about queuing background work. Is there any reason why it wouldn't work for you?

How critical is that the background processing will complete, after the client has received the 200 OK response? Are you OK with, for example, a 0.01% chance that the processing will not happen because of a server-restart or other reasons?

@ZdeněkJelínek I  have seen the post. thank you for that. But how I can pass the data from request to background service as soon as the api call is initiated?

@TheodorZoulias Thank you for your response. We have the restart in off hours and I do not think the data loss during the restart.

There's also this previous question and this one which is specific to hosted services, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork?view=net-8.0#system-componentmodel-backgroundworker-dowork. I don't know that all of those are relevant, but they seem so.

If you need to return success before the operation has completed, the correct response code is 202 Accepted, not 200 OK.

In a real-world scenario, the API should receive requests from clients and then forward these messages to an event delivery system such as RabbitMQ or Kafka. Subsequently, one of your consumers, responsible for message consumption, listens to these queues and starts processing the messages.
However, if you wish to proceed without using these systems, you can implement a queued hosted service or mediator pattern. It's important to note that if your API crashes, any messages in transit may be lost. If the data is critical, consider persisting it by storing it in a database.
If you still prefer to pass data to a BackgroundService without utilizing these strategies, you can store the data in memory (e.g., using EF Core or memory cache). Then, in your ExecuteAsync method, you can proceed with the processing.
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // retrieve data - from memory, db or some static list
        var myData = GetDataFromMemory();

        if (myData.Length > 0)
        {
            // do the long running process
        }


        // make sure delay to prevent excessive CPU usage.
        await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
    }
}

Sorry for not showing all the strategies with samples; they won't fit in one comment

Thanks @Ogulcan . I am going to try your suggestions.  I also find this repo which used Fire and forget handler.  I am going to try this as well.
What do you you think if there are any downsides of using this?https://github.com/MikeyFriedChicken/WebAPI.FireForgetRepository/blob/master/Database/FireForgetRepositoryHandler.cs

You're welcome @alienavatar, this would be the most straightforward way, but since your process is long-running, you should use _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {  }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach); but for each call, this will create a new task from  ThreadPool. Just imagine 2000 customers make a request to this endpoint, then it will consume memory + threads. There could also be concurrency problems if you're doing some I/O-related things. I recommend doing this with an event-delivery system + asp.net core API + background service
